# Bootstrap 4 - 3 images and a form inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

im trying to replicate this image as an exercise. [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJUQH.jpg)

But, right now it looks like this. [current homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMoOK.jpg)

Based on my html file, under 'banner' comment, i created a 'jumbo div' so that all elements inside it wrap in a full width dekstop. Then, under 'jumbo div' i created some 'col-sm-n container' so that the elements inside my 'jumbo div' take the amount of space which i assigned.

**So, my questions is this the correct way for me to do it to achieve just like the original image. And if yes, what did i do wrong because there are like huge gap after the navbar and those elements not inline.**

```css
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 'Roboto', 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 30px;
}

#navbarSupportedContent {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.btn {
  padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.btn-outline-light:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn-outline-light.focus, .btn-outline-light:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin: 2.2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100% !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #bf1e2e;
  padding:13px 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #bf1e2e;
}

.dropdown-menu > li{
  display:inline-block;
}

ul.navbar-nav li:hover > div.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Intermark Mall | Welcome</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style2.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Header -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #bf1e2e;">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/213n9mc.png" width="275" height="90" alt="">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link navbarDropdownMenuLink" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              ABOUT
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mall Info</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Precincts</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mall Location</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Getting There</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Car Park Info</a>
            </div>

          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link navbarDropdownMenuLink" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              STORES
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Directory</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Promotions</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Floor Plan</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link navbarDropdownMenuLink" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              HAPPENINGS
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Events</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link navbarDropdownMenuLink" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              CONTACT
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Talk to Us!</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="#" role="button">TOURIST PRIVILEGE</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<!-- Banners -->
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <figure class="col-sm-3">
          <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/140mer.jpg"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/2462d89.jpg"/>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <figure class="col-sm-2">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                Check me out
              </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3">
          <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/2rvyo0h.jpg"/>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>









  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**element is itself an inline element.** If you want all images to be align side by side use the **max-width:100%;** and float the elements properly and clear float in the end. As you are using bootstrap classes then use them in combination of col-3 to place all four images in one line.

```css
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 'Roboto', 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 30px;
}

#navbarSupportedContent {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.btn {
  padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.btn-outline-light:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn-outline-light.focus, .btn-outline-light:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin: 2.2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100% !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #bf1e2e;
  padding:13px 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #bf1e2e;
}

.dropdown-menu > li{
  display:inline-block;
}

ul.navbar-nav li:hover > div.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

figure img{max-width:100%}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Intermark Mall | Welcome</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style2.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Header -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #bf1e2e;">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/213n9mc.png" width="275" height="90" alt="">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link navbarDropdownMenuLink" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              ABOUT
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mall Info</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Precincts</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mall Location</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Getting There</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Car Park Info</a>
            </div>

          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link navbarDropdownMenuLink" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              STORES
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Directory</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Promotions</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Floor Plan</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link navbarDropdownMenuLink" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              HAPPENINGS
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Events</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link navbarDropdownMenuLink" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              CONTACT
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Talk to Us!</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="#" role="button">TOURIST PRIVILEGE</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<!-- Banners -->
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <figure class="col-sm-3">
          <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/140mer.jpg"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3">
          <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/140mer.jpg"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3">
          <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/140mer.jpg"/>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3">
          <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/140mer.jpg"/>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <figure class="col-sm-2">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                Check me out
              </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-sm-3">
          <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/2rvyo0h.jpg"/>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>









  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not really understand it but ok i'll try to play around with each img float.

Comment: The blocks you are using are bootstrap( so floating is already there). Use ( max-width:100%) on images so that they be inside the box and show fully. or use on box in which the images are places( overflow:hidden) so that the images don't show outside of the box.